# Partitioning data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have the following data set and i am trying to use a row rank logic in order to get the output mentioned below:

```
declare  @data table
       ( 
          identifier int,
          value float,
          dateValue datetime
        )
insert into @data values( 1 , 100 ,'2016-08-09 11:00:00.000')
insert into @data values( 1 , 150 ,'2016-08-09 11:00:00.000')
insert into @data values( 1 , 200 ,'2014-08-09 11:00:00.000')
insert into @data values( 2 , 400 ,'2016-08-09 11:00:00.000')
insert into @data values( 2 , 300 ,'2012-08-09 11:00:00.000')
```

the output i was expecting was : to pick up the first value for Value column based on the latest date for a given id and the aggregation for a given id.

```
id  Value  AggValue         Date
1   100      450           2016-08-09 11:00:00.000
2   400      700           2016-08-09 11:00:00.000
```

I tried using the following query to get similar output but i couldn't figure out how to calculate the Aggvalue in the same query

```
SELECT identifier,value,dateValue FROM
      (SELECT  identifier,value,dateValue,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.identifier ORDER BY t.dateValue DESC) AS [Rank]
      FROM @data t) AS [sub]
      where [sub].[Rank] = 1
```

Comment: The term "partitioning" is typically used to describe the physical storage of the rows of a single table in different "sub-tables". It is not used to describe the usage of the `partition by` condition in a window function.

Comment: i think you want this.
SELECT identifier,value,dateValue FROM
      (SELECT  identifier,value,dateValue, sum(value) as AggValue
      FROM @data t) AS [sub] group by identifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SUM() OVER`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES identifier id,value,SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY identifier) AggValue,dateValue
FROM @data
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY datevalue DESC)
```

**Result:**

```
id          value                  AggValue               dateValue
----------- ---------------------- ---------------------- -----------------------
1           100                    450                    2016-08-09 11:00:00.000
2           400                    700                    2016-08-09 11:00:00.000
```

Comment: I like the `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES` in this context!

Answer (score 0):

You just miss to **SUM(value)**:

```
SELECT 
    identifier,
    value,
    dateValue 
FROM
(
    SELECT  
        identifier,
        dateValue,
        SUM(VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY t.identifier ORDER BY t.identifier) AS Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.identifier ORDER BY t.dateValue DESC) AS [Rank]
    FROM @data t
) AS [sub]
where [sub].[Rank] = 1
```